# Creating a Database Interface

Tags: c#, t-sql

I am new to creating interfaces and was wondering if anyone knows of good tutorials/Examples of how to create them. I code mainly ASP.NET, C# and T-SQL. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please clarify the notion of a *database interface*?

Comment: Could you be more specific?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? How to write a data access layer? This question seems way too broad.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is an ORM, take a look at Linq to SQL

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want to look into is [ADO.NET Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a fairly sophisticated three-tier app in VB after reading one of the [Murach](http://www.murach.com) books.  There's one for C# and ASP.NET on VS 2008.

Answer (score 1):

The concepts outlined in this tutorial helped me a lot a few years ago - it's quite detailed but might be quite out of date now (SQL Server 2005)

http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/creating-a-data-access-layer-cs

But it's directly aimed at C# ASP.NET, so should be suited to you I think.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using an existing ORM mapper instead of building your own data access layer from scratch as a lot of it is boiler plate code any way. A popular one in the .NET community is [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx)